# How create a link on the master page when ever no one is signed in

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, anonymous-authentication

I created a site with anonymous access and forms based authentication. Now I want to show the link to create a new user in the master page when ever no one is signed in. Can any one please help to achieve this process? Following are the screen shots for more details.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a delegate control and user control to check to your master page, and check  if the user is anonymous then show the link :)

Add a Delegate control to your master page:

```
   <SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server" ControlId="PageHeader">
    </SharePoint:DelegateControl>
```

Only thing to note here at this stage is the ControlId attribute - the Feature we create will use this to substitute the real user/server control.

Then we have the feature.xml file, where we specify the feature details (including scope):

```
<Feature xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/" Id="373042ED-718D-46e2-9596-50379DA4D522"
Title="COB.Demos.DelegateControls"
Description="Specifies which user control should be used for the 'PageHeader' DelegateControl used on the site master page. The replacement user control is stored in the CONTROLTEMPLATES directory." Scope="Farm"
Hidden="FALSE"
Version="1.0.0.0">
<ElementManifests>
<ElementManifest Location="elements.xml"/>
</ElementManifests>
</Feature>
```

the 'instructions' for the feature are in the element manifest:

```
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
<!-- using a sequence number LOWER than default of 100 so our custom control gets loaded -->
<Control Id="PageHeader" Sequence="90" ControlSrc="~/_ControlTemplates/COBPageHeader.ascx" />
</Elements>
```

In the COBPageHeader.ascx code-behind, add the logic of hiding link.

Comment: For anonymous we have to show the link to register... :)

Comment: ok, whatever ;), but hopefully you will develop it :)

Comment: Here Instead of that feature.xml and element.xml we can do one thing. Just add an empty element and refer the control id and other parameters. Just change the scope of the feature in feature editor scree. Thats it.! this way works successfully!! Thank you brother

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the CurrentUser has a LoginName which is not an empty string attached to the SPContext.Current.User object. If the LoginName is null or empty, then the user is anonymous.

Code here:
http://spdailytips.blogspot.in/2011/09/programmatically-verify-if-current-user.html

You can write the code in a delegate control which will be attached to the Master Page. The Delegate Control will check If the user is anonymous, and if yes,  push the link to the page.

Comment: thank you.. But where I want to add that user checking code in master page?

Comment: Just search for how to add a delegate control to a page

Answer (score 0):

I have recently made use of this feature, made use of a delegate control to accomplish this

Comment: Welcome to SharePoint StackExchange. Although your answer may answer the question, there isn't enough content to produce a suitable working solution. Please read the [FAQ][1] for more information [1]:http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/faq